# Allow CORS for b2_delete_file_version

Tags: cors, backblaze

According to the [Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html) documentation: [CORS: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/cors_rules.html), I can only set cors for those capabilities :

- b2_download_file_by_id
- b2_download_file_by_name
- b2_upload_file
- b2_upload_part

I'm using [b2 CLI](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/quick_command_line.html) to define CORS rules for my bucket, And all my requests work fine from my origin **https:||foo.yz.**

But when I try to delete a file using b2_delete_file_version API I get this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api002.backblazeb2.com/b2api/v2/b2_delete_file_version' from origin 'https:||foo.yz' has been blocked by CORS policy
```

- Although it works when I send my request from postman

but when I try to add this capability: "b2_delete_file_version" to my CORS rules
it shows me that message :

```
unknown allowedOperation value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct - at present, those are the only four B2 API operations that may be CORS-enabled. However, you could take advantage of [B2's S3 compatibility](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/s3_compatible_api.html); the following S3 compatible operations are supported for CORS:

- `s3_delete`
- `s3_get`
- `s3_head`
- `s3_post`
- `s3_put`

If `s3_delete` doesn't work for you, please feel free to email our product management team at productfeedback@backblaze.com with your use case and we can look at adding `b2_delete_file_version`.